# Rendering HTML data which contains math equations in a webview

Tags: android, android-webview, mathjax

I want to display Html data into webview which also contains Math equations using MathJax but in my application i am not able to render math equations

I tried using below code

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x- mathjax-config'>"
            + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
            + "showMathMenu: false, "
            + "jax: ['input/MathML','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
            + "extensions: ['mml2jax.js'], "
            + "TeX: { extensions: ['noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
            //+"'SVG' : { blacker: 30, "
            // +"styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } "
            + "});</script>"
            + "<script type='text/javascript' "
            + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
            +"<script type= 'text/javascript' "
            +"src=http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
            + "></script><span id='text'> </span> <span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");


    String htmlFilename = "test.html";
    AssetManager mgr = getBaseContext().getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream in = mgr.open(htmlFilename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER);
        String htmlContentInStringFormat = StreamToString(in);
        in.close();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='"
                                    + "<math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">"
                                    + "<mstyle displaystyle=\"true\">"
                                    + doubleEscapeTeX(htmlContentInStringFormat)
                                    + "</mstyle></math>';");
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        } else {
            webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='<font color=\"#000000\">`" + doubleEscapeTeX(htmlContentInStringFormat) + "`</font>';", null);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

I am loading HTMl file from assets but its not getting rendered

test.html

Euclid’s Division Lemma states that for positive integers *c* and *d* with     c>d, there exists unique integers *q* and *r* satisfying the condition     c=dq+r such that     0≤r<d.

Let, any positive integer is *c* and     d=3.

Now, according to Euclid’s algorithm     c=3q+r for some other integer     q≥0.

All the possible values of remainder are 0, 1, 2 as it satisfies the condition     0≤r<3. Now, the possible values of *c* are     3q or     3q+1 or     3q+2.

Case 1: If     c=3q.

c     3        =     (             3q     )     3                      =27     q     3                      =9(           9       q       3                )              =9m

Case 2: If     c=3q+1.

c     3        =     (             3q+1     )     3                      =27     q     3        +27     q     2        +9q+1              =9(           3       q       3            +3       q       2            +q    )+1              =9m+1

Case 2: If     c=3q+2.

c     3        =     (             3q+2     )     3                      =27     q     3        +54     q     2        +36q+8              =9(           3       q       3            +6       q       2            +4q    )+8              =9m+8

Hence, the cube of any positive integer is of the form     9m,     9m+1 or     9m+8.

Comment: Well, the `type='text/x- mathjax-config'` should not have a space in it, so if that isn't a typo here, that would mean that MathJax doesn't recognize the configuration script, and so doesn't run it.  That would mean there is no input or output processor specified (there is no default one), and so no math will be processed.  That would account for your results.  So try using `type='text/x-mathjax-config'` with no space and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I see that MathJax is used to interpret MathML language.

So I suggest you to use GeckoView insteadof WebView.

GeckoView has a build in support of MathML

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView.

I post a piece of code to show you how to reach the asset file which is in the html subdirectory.

The only problem is that you increase your apk's weight (+30Mo).

[image]

[image]

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GeckoView view = findViewById(R.id.geckoview);
    GeckoSession session = new GeckoSession();
    GeckoRuntime runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this);

    session.open(runtime);
    view.setSession(session);

    session.loadUri("resource://android/assets/html/myMathMLFile.html");
}
```